# Tasks in Kanban View: card rearrangement error when Project/User is only authorized to modify his own tasks

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, kanban

This happens when a Project/User drops his task unto a destination stage containing tasks not owned by him.

Apparently, Odoo remembers the stack ordering of tasks within a stage via `project.task.sequence`, and updates all the task cards' `sequence` fields when the Project/User completes the drop action. But since the Project/User is not authorized to modify other users' tasks (of `project.task` object type). The Odoo server raises the exception shown below.

[image]

Access restriction is implemented via the following record rule for Project/User:

```
Name: Project/Task: only assignee and creator can modify task
Object: Task (project.task)
Apply for: Write
Domain filter: ['|',('user_id','=',user.id),('create_uid','=',user.id)] 
Group name: Project/User
```

Is there any workaround to this problem?

At time of writing, the error can be reproduced at http://demo.odoo.com currently running Odoo version 8.saas~6.

Note that by default Human Resources / Employees are allowed to modify tasks not assigned to them, so the write and delete access of  record rule **"Project/Task: employees: public, portal, employee or (followers and following)"** must first be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't think of a better solution, so I just did the following hack instead:

Add to top portion of `_write` function of `openerp.models.BaseModel` in the file **ODOO_ROOT/models.py**:

```
def _write(self, cr, user, ids, vals, context=None):
    # use admin if just writing to 'sequence' field of model 'project.task'
    if self._name == 'project.task' and vals.keys() == ['sequence']:
        user = SUPERUSER_ID
```

This is probably OK since the sequence field is not really a very important field to protect from casual modification by non-owners.